# Is there a way to get rid of this error bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python2: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: centos, yum

Is there some other way to sort this out without having to manually get the packages using the RPM?

Comment: `python2` is a system program. Please do not touch or change. ........ Reinstall with e.g. : `# rpm -Uvh --force  python-2.7.5-89.el7.x86_64.rpm`  http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.9.2009/os/x86_64/Packages/python-2.7.5-89.el7.x86_64.rpm ..... if CentOS 7. ... Ref. http://mirror.centos.org/centos/

Comment: How did you even manage to uninstall python without your package manager - I'm not even assuming it's Yum at this point - throwing out several warnings?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to U&L SE. `yum` is a Python program...

```
» head -1 /usr/bin/yum
#!/usr/bin/python

» ll /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 7 Nov 29  2020 /usr/bin/python -> python2
```

...and as such requires Python to be present. Normally, the system you run yum on will have Python installed to satisfy that requirement. Since you obviously can't use `yum` to install Python, I see no alternative than to install the python rpms.